# python creating a class at runtime containing another class

Tags: python, google-app-engine, types

I wanted to generate a class at runtime like the following:

```
from google.appengine.ext.db import djangoforms

class TestForm(ConsumerForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Consumer
```

I can use

```
form_model = type("TestForm", (djangoforms.ModelForm,), {})
```

to create the TestForm class but I'm not sure how to create the Meta class inside it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create it in the same manner as `TestForm` and put it into `TesForm`'s dictionary:

```
Meta = type("Meta", (), {"model": Consumer})
TestForm = type("TestForm", (djangoforms.ModelForm,), {"Meta": Meta})
```

(Disclaimer: I'd usually avoid dynamically creating classes.)

Comment: @sven-marnach Is there any SO question where your comment from the disclaimer is discussed?

Comment: @mloskot: Not sure.  I'd generally avoid any metaprogramming techniques unless they provide significant code simplification.  Metaprogramming code is much harder to read and less straight-forward.